# How can I use std::endl in a custom std::ostream class

Tags: c++, templates, std

I am creating a custom ostream class which is briefly exposed in the following snippet. I would like to be able to use `std::endl` but the compiler does not let me. I don’t understand why.

```
#include <iostream> 

struct Bar
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
};

template <typename T, typename U>
Foo<T>& operator<<(Foo<T>& _foo, U&&)
{
  return _foo;
}

int main()
{
  Foo<Bar> f;
  f << "aa" << std::endl;
}
```

The error gcc 4.7.1 gives me is:

> main.cpp:21:21: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘operator<< ((* & f), (*"aa")) << std::endl’ main.cpp:21:21:
>   note: candidates are: main.cpp:13:9: note: template
>   Foo& operator<<(Foo&, U&&) main.cpp:13:9: note:   template
>   argument deduction/substitution failed: main.cpp:21:21: note:
>   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’

Why can’t it deduce parameter U? Shouldn’t this be `typeof(std::endl)` ?

Comment: We have `decltype` and `typeid` for that.

Comment: @oldrinb some operator from java. I meant `decltype` .

Comment: Why do you have a custom ostream? Most of the time people think they want a custom ostream, a custom streambuf will do what they want with a lot less work.

Comment: @qdii that's not true either, though... are you thinking of `instanceof`? :-)

Comment: @oldrinb ah yea :) The bright side is that I never use any of them, I suppose.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I never thought of that to be honest.

Comment: @qdii note that `decltype` is a compile-time way to determine the type of some variable at its declaration, while `instanceof` is a runtime check that an object can be treated as.

Comment: Probably at least worth considering.

Comment: Change right reference to const reference: `U&&` to `const U&`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `std::endl` is

```
namespace std {
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
}
```

Your class is not derived from `basic_ostream`, so it cannot work.

And `basic_ostream` has

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<
(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&))
```

for works with manipulators like `std::endl`.

Comment: Ok, but can I really derive from `basic_ostream`? I thought its destructor was not virtual.

Comment: @qdii Why you need your own stream class? So, for example `std::basic_ostringstream` is derived from `std::basic_ostream`. And `std::basic_ostream` has virtual d-tor.

Answer (score 3):

Note, that there is rarely a need to use the template approach nor is there a good use of deriving from `std::ostream` for a different purpose than convenient initialization of a `std::ostream` with a custom `std::streambuf`. To create new sources or targets to read from or write to, you derive from `std::streambuf`. For a stream writing you typically overwrite `std:;streambuf::overflow()` and `std::streambuf::sync()`.